# Setting up Kleopatra in vb.net Solution Explorer

Tags: vb.net, azure-devops

I have Kleopatra loaded on my PC and I created a key/pair for my keypairID and I created a VB.net script that creates an encrypted file in the specified directory – it all works great to create the TestText.txt.gpg file.

I am a bit of newbie to this whole world of VSTS and I’m not sure what should be included in the Solution Explorer to now run this from a production server – not my PC. Which elements (.exe or .dll, etc) of Keopatra should be included and under which option like under the "Solution Explorer > Add" menu should I use to add them so the production job can find the keypair and execute the gpg.exe?

When I installed Kleopatra on my PC it created two folders C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win (contains the kleopatra.exe) and C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG (contains the gpg.exe).

Please don’t suggest using something else the vendor insisted on Kleopatra encryption.

It there is a tutorial or youtube you can share that explains how to set this kind of situation up to use 3rd party executables that would be awesome! Thank you!

```
Sub Main()

    Dim sourceName As String = "TestText.txt"
    Dim toencryptedFileName As String = ("C:\Folder1\Folder2\" & sourceName)
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo

    'Location of the binary on my PC
    p.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"     
    p.Arguments = "--batch --yes --recipient keypairID --encrypt " & toencryptedFileName
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    Process.Start(p)

End Sub
```

Comment: The hosted agent don't have Kleopatra capability, you can not use it, you need to [deploy an private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts). You can try to run the script on private agent machine directly...

Answer (score 0):

On my PC this worked fine to create the file: filename.csv.gpg
Note: You need download and install Kleopatra and then you can import the public key supplied to you from some other recipient for the “reciptname” into Kleopatra. There are instructions for that here: https://www.deepdotweb.com/2015/02/21/pgp-tutorial-for-windows-kleopatra-gpg4win/

```
095:    Dim Extract_File As String  = C:\Extracts\ProgramName\filename.csv”
‘This line calls the function:
096:    FileEncrypted = Encrypt_File(Extract_File, Batch_Timestamp)

   Private Function Encrypt_File(File_To_Encrypt As String, Batch_Timestamp As Date)
100:    On Error GoTo Encrypt_File_Error
110:    Dim Success As Boolean = False
120:    Dim sourceName As String = File_To_Encrypt
130:    Dim gpgProcess = New Process()
140:    gpgProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "gpg.exe"
150:    gpgProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
160:    gpgProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
170:    gpgProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--batch --yes --recipient reciptname --encrypt " & sourceName
180:    gpgProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
190:    gpgProcess.Start()
200:    Success = True
Encrypt_File_Exit:
210:    On Error Resume Next
220:    gpgProcess.WaitForExit()
230:    gpgProcess.Close()
240:    Return Success
250:    Exit Function
Encrypt_File_Error:
260:    Error_Handler("SomeModule.vb", "Encrypt_File", Err, System_Output, Batch_Timestamp)
270:    Resume Encrypt_File_Exit
    End Function
```